# Oracle Update - JSON Merge Patch with more than 4000 characters

Tags: json, merge, oracle19c

I'm trying to update JSON value to a column (CLOB data type) in an oracle table. The JSON value is more than 4000 characters and the number of characters is dynamic based on the data received from the application.  JSON_MERGEPATCH is used to merging the value to the existing JSON content already present in the table.

I'm using java as the programming and doing a batch update (ojdbc8 jar) to write updates to oracle table. I notice that while using JSON_MERGEPATCH when the number of characters exceeds 40000, the CLOB is updated to NULL and I lose the pre-existing data in the table. Is there anyway to resolve this issue and merge the new fields to the existing JSON?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; the `INSERT` statement for some sample data that demonstrates the issue; **YOUR** Java and sql code where you are using `JSON_MERGEPATCH`; the input parameters; and the expected output. If you talk about the code but don't show us an example then we either can't answer the question or need to try to guess what the code is you are using and what the exact nature of the issue is. Please help us to help you and give us all the information needed to replicate the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for `JSON_MERGEPATCH` is in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/JSON_MERGEPATCH.html#GUID-2004F536-BE60-4457-A1A8-AB908FFF5399):

> [image: JSON_MERGEPATCH syntax]

If you do not include the "returning clause" then `JSON_MERGEPATCH` will default to returning a `VARCHAR2` value and if this exceeds 4000 bytes then the default "on error clause" will be applied which is `NULL ON ERROR`.

If you want to return a `CLOB` value then you need to specify the "returning clause":

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET   value = JSON_MERGEPATCH(value, :newvalue RETURNING CLOB)
WHERE id = 1;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ba13f331b822efedcecac6b1bf9a3c9f)*

Comment: Thanks, this works.

Comment: Worth noting that It's possible to extent the size of varchar in Oracle to be 32k. This can help if you want to continue to use strings as opposed to BLOB or the native JSON datatype.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/refrn/MAX_STRING_SIZE.html#GUID-D424D23B-0933-425F-BC69-9C0E6724693C