# Oracle - json_mergepatch updating column to NULL

Tags: sql, json, oracle, sql-update, oracle19c

I have a table column with a JSON:

```
{ "name":"Tony","age":"20","sex":"male" }
```

When I try to add new data with a `json_mergepatch`:

```sql
UPDATE users SET user =
  json_mergepatch(user, '{"email":"tony@mail.com"}')
where name = 'Tony';
```

My column data becomes `Null` instead of `{ "name":"Tony","age":"20","sex":"male", "email":"tony@mail.com" }`

see fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7cbe31629bb709d1bbe7056fc6710673
Fiddle works, but on my code it doesn't for some reason. My JSON is valid.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

---

It seems that Oracle has a limit of 4000 characters for JSON even if the column is CLOB. When operating with `json_mergepatch` if the column has 4000 characters it makes it NULL!
Found this trough testing.

Is there a way to overcome this limitation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution here: [Oracle Update - JSON Merge Patch with more than 4000 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69749922/oracle-update-json-merge-patch-with-more-than-4000-characters)

```
UPDATE users SET user =
  json_mergepatch(user, '{"email":"tony@mail.com"}' RETURNING CLOB)
where name = 'Tony';
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id    NUMBER,
  xuser  VARCHAR2(4000),
  CONSTRAINT users_is_json CHECK (xuser IS JSON)
);

INSERT INTO users (id, xuser) VALUES (1, '{ "name":"Tony","age":"20","sex":"male" }');

UPDATE users a 
SET    a.xuser = JSON_MERGEPATCH(a.xuser, '{"email":"tony@email.com"}') 
WHERE  a.xuser.name = 'Tony';

SELECT * FROM users;

ID  XUSER
--  -----
1   
{
"name" : "Tony",
"age" : "20",
"sex" : "male",
"email" : "tony@xmail.com"
}
```

Since "user" is an oracle reserved word and it should be avoided to use those, I named it "xuser". When I remove the alias "a" it errors out with `ORA-00904: "XUSER"."NAME": invalid identifier`