# Update CLOB JSON column with case gives ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got CLOB

Tags: sql, json, oracle, clob, oracle19c

I have a CLOB column containing JSON, I want to update the values of the JSON using `json_mergepatch`. If the column is NULL then `json_mergepatch` doesn't work, so in this case I just want to add the new JSON as given.

I must use CLOB to avoid this issue: [Oracle Update - JSON Merge Patch with more than 4000 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69749922/oracle-update-json-merge-patch-with-more-than-4000-characters)

This works and updates the column:

```
UPDATE my_table SET data =
  json_mergepatch(data, '{ "user": "Tony" }' RETURNING CLOB)
where id = '1';
```

This gives `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got CLOB`:

```
UPDATE my_table SET data =
   case
      when (data is NULL) then '{ "user": "Tony" }'
      else json_mergepatch(data, '{ "user": "Tony" }' RETURNING CLOB)
   end
where id = '1';
```

Why doesn't it work with `case`? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most probably in the fact, that the `CASE` returns a not expected data type.

Contrary to your claim, the `json_mergepatch` **works** fine also on a `NULL` JSON column, but the result remains `NULL` (which you do not expects).

Not sure is this is the most elegant solution, but it *apparently works* by changing the `NULL` to an *empty JSON* with `NVL`

```
UPDATE tab SET data =
  json_mergepatch(nvl(data,'{}'), '{ "user": "Tony" }' RETURNING CLOB)
where id = 1;
```