# Oracle APEX - Returning clob doesn't work

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle19c

In Oracle 19c this works, testing on SQL developer:

```sql
   update
      my_table
   set
      my_col = json_mergepatch(
         nvl(my_col,'{}'), :patch returning clob
      )
   where
      id = '1';
```

But on Oracle Application Express Resource template it for some reason silently fails because of the `returning clob`. I added the `returning clob` to solve this isue [Oracle Update - JSON Merge Patch with more than 4000 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69749922/oracle-update-json-merge-patch-with-more-than-4000-characters)

Is there a way to solve it without having the `returning clob` part or another way to make it work on Oracle Application Express?

Comment: If you don't want it to fail silently you could use the "on error" clause - `returning clob ERROR ON ERROR` - to see what the error is

Comment: check this https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:846056192691